# LegendGraphic gray color from external SLD file

Tags: geoserver, legend

I'm trying to add legendgraphic from a WMS layer with an external SLD file wich is generated dynamicly. The legend is added but the colors from SLD file are all gray. The WMS layer is colored by SLD filters. In legend the filters are gray.
[image]
The code used is:

```
if(value_selected=="Pret/mp")
            {
            document.getElementById("map").style.width = "90%";
            spatii.mergeNewParams({SLD: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/proprietati/tmpo/<?php echo $identificator; ?>_spatii_pretmp.sld",STYLES: null});
            spatii.redraw(true);
            document.getElementById("legenda").innerHTML = "<img src=\"http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/proprietati/wms?Service=WMS&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&WIDTH=14&HEIGHT=14&LAYER=<?php echo $identificator."_spatii";?>&SLD=http://127.0.0.1:8080/proprietati/tmpo/<?php echo $identificator; ?>_spatii_pretmp.sld\" />";

            }
        if(value_selected=="Default")
            {
            document.getElementById("map").style.width = "100%";
            spatii.mergeNewParams({SLD:null});
            spatii.redraw(true);
            }

    }
```

**EDIT**
Here is the LOG section from geoserver:

```
Request: getLegendGraphic
    Strict = true
    Height = 14
    Width = 14
    Locale = null
    Format = image/png
    Rules = []
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=proprietati:ro25858_spatii]]
    FeatureType = null
    Layers = [SimpleFeatureTypeImpl http://proprietati:ro25858_spatii identified extends Feature(geom:geom,id_spatiu:id_spatiu,identificator:identificator,id_cladire:id_cladire,info:info,numar_contract:numar_contract,beneficiar:beneficiar,pret_total:pret_total)]
    Env = {}
    Scale = -1.0
    Transparent = false
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    LegendOptions = {}
    Version = 1.0.0
    Request = GetLegendGraphic
    RawKvp = {EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml, REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic, FORMAT=image/png, VERSION=1.0.0, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=14, SLD=http://127.0.0.1:8080/proprietati/tmpo/ro25858_spatii_pretmp.sld, HEIGHT=14, LAYER=proprietati:ro25858_spatii}
    Get = false
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8000/geoserver/
    RequestCharset = null
```

**EDIT2**
Geoserver is getting the data ok in style visualisation. I don't get it. Here is the picture:
[image]

**EDIT3**
Still no solution found. 
As a workaround - I've generated my Legend from  with CSS and PHP

Comment: dould it be that GeoServer is using the default Polygon style for your layer? consult the log file to see what is happening

Comment: The default style has a green color. Not gray. I thought about that. But it couoldn't be that. I guess

Comment: can you turn logging up to geoserver developer, run the request and paste that section of the log file into the question please

Comment: I've inserted the log into the question

Comment: is 'proprietati:ro25858_spatii' a generated SLD or the one you uploaded?

Comment: I've uploaded in geoserver the same style generated with sld. I will try to remove the uploaded style from geoserver and see what happens.

Comment: Still same. No change.